# trace32 cmm command to load CE symbols

Tags: command, windows-ce, symbols, lauterbach

I need to load CE symbols after every target reset in trace32 debugger. I need to every time click this button (load CE symbols) [image]

And i need to select **nt A8_0(jumpered)** as shown in fig : [image]

How can i do this using cmm command ? I also want to do this every 10 mins time interval like wait or sleep events?

Answer (score 2):

I am almost sure that both the toolbar button and the dialog are not part of a regular TRACE32 installation. **Did you know that TRACE32 users can add their own buttons and dialogs?** (See commands MENU and DIALOG) The text "Which ASIC?" sounds really like a dialog spedific to your company/department.

So if you have colleagues, which provide scripts for your debug sessions, I suggest to ask them.

Otherwise you might want to try the following:

- Check your CMM scripts and also script C:\T32\t32.cmm for the execution of any MENU and DIALOG commands.
- Check your scripts for the executions of other scripts (DO command).
- Check if one of the script call a *.men or *.dlg file (Menu or dialog description file), since menu or dialog definitions can be embedded into a CMM script or placed in separate files.
- The command(s) you are searching should be somewhere in such a menu or dialog definition.
- Search in your setup files for the string "nt A8_0(jumpered)".

Otherwise it might help if you provide the CMM scripts you use to start your debug session.

---

For executing any a CMM script after fixed time interval you can try the command `GLOBALON TIME 600.s DO <myscript.cmm>`
This will execute the script after 10 minutes.

So if you want to execute the script periodically you have to place this GLOBALON TIME command again in the end of your script.

---

However if you intention is *to refresh the debug symbols after calling your makefile* I suggest not to use GLOBALON TIME. Instead I suggest the following to steps:

1. Write a CMM script 'myscript.cmm' to reload your debug symbols (same as before)
2. Enable the remote API port of your TRACE32 application (RCL=NETASSIST in C:\T32\config.t32)
3. Trigger your CMM script to reload your debug symbols from your makefile after the build with the t32rem.exe console application. Lìke this:

   ```
   C:\T32\bin\windows\t32rem.exe localhost port=20000 "DO myscript.cmm"
   ```

Comment: another cmm has a Dialog (DEFBUTTON "nT A8_0 (Jumpered)" "GOTO nanoTesla_Common")  how will i execute it in my cmm script ?

Comment: Search in your script 'another.cmm' for a line starting with the label “nanoTesla_Common:". The lines following this label are the commands which get executed, when you hit the "nT A8_0…" button.

Comment: Explanation: The first string after DEFBUTTON  is the buttons title, while the second string is the CMM command which get executed when you hit the button. In you case it's a GOTO command gets executed. Thus, you have to find the target of the GOTO command. (Personally I think using GOTO in a dialog is bad style.)

Comment: thanks! How do i exit trace32 application itself through cmm command ? it must close the window

Comment: You welcome. If my answer solved your issue, please mark it as "solved". To close the TRACE32 application from script use command QUIT.